# how do you disable the livereload plugin in docpad

Tags: docpad, livereload

I see I have to set the liveReload plugin eanbled to false, but not sure where to set it.  Is there a plugin config section somewhere in docpad.coffee

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the root folder of your docpad project edit the docpad.coffee file (or docpad.js)

```
docpadConfig:
    ...
    # enabled example for live configuration
    plugins:
        livereload:
            enabled: true

    # enabled example for different environments
    environments:
        development: # change the name here if you have other environments
            plugins:
                livereload:
                    enabled: true
        staging: # change the name here if you have other environments
            plugins:
                livereload:
                    enabled: true
    ...
```

more information about the configuration file is here - http://docpad.org/docs/config